# Perl Mutex Doesn't Seem to be working

Tags: perl, mutex

I have the following perl mutex code:

```
# ClaimMutex
#
# Return the mutex on success and undef on failure
#
# The mutex will be released if it's out of its scope
#
sub ClaimMutex {
    my ($mutexName) = @_;
    my $mutex = Win32::Mutex->new(0, $mutexName);
    if (!defined $mutex) {
        EPrint("Failed to create a mutex: $^E\n");
        return;
    }
    if($mutex->wait(0) == 0) {
        TPrint("Waiting for another instance of $mutexName to finish\n");
        if ($mutex->wait() == 0) {
            EPrint("Failed to get a $mutexName mutex lock: $^E\n");
            return;
        }
    }

    return OnDestroy($mutex, sub { $_[0]->Release(); });
}
```

And I call it with:

```
sub Export
{
  my ($rOptions) = @_;

  my $mutex = ClaimMutex("export");
  if (!defined $mutex)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  ...
   read from d:\foo.txt
   copy d:\foo.txt to d:\foobackup.txt
   write to d:\foo.txt
   ...
 }
```

This is running in parallel on two separate instances of Perl.  However, I did I procmon while they are running, and I saw that one instance opened d:\foo.txt for write, and never finished writing before the other instance tried to open it for read (and failed the open).  I'm confused, as I thought that the mutex was going to prevent this.  I verified the only place that does anything in foo.txt is in the Export sub.  Do you have any suggestions for what might be going on?

Comment: **TRY THIS**: before you spawn any other threads, create the mutex using `my $global_lock = Win32::Mutex->new (0, $mutexName)`, and when trying to aquire ownership (ie. working with the mutex previously created) use `my $mutex = Win32::Mutex->open ($mutexName)`. (I am not familiar with the internals of `Win32::Mutex`, but it wouldn't surprise me if your code creates a new mutex each time - instead of referring to previously created entities).

Comment: They're thin wrappers over the system calls CreateMutex, OpenMutex, etc. // The OP said he had two processes, not two threads in one process.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.

Apparently there was a condition added around the mutex (which would end up as true), but I think that the mutex was going out of scope after the if method.

Essentially, it looked like:

```
if($trueVar == "1")
{
  my $mutex = ClaimMutex("export");
  if (!defined $mutex)
  {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you posted does not suffer from the bug you describe, and neither does the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Object::Destroyer qw( );
use Win32::Mutex      qw( );

sub mutex_nb {
    my ($name) = @_;    
    my $mutex = Win32::Mutex->new(0, $name)
        or die("Can't create mutex: $^E\n");

    my $rv = $mutex->wait(0);
    die("Can't wait for mutex: $^E\n")
        if !defined($rv);
    die("Can't wait for mutex: Abandonned mutex\n")
        if $rv < 0;
    return undef
        if $rv == 0;

    return Object::Destroyer->new($mutex, 'Release');
}

sub main {
   my $mutex = mutex_nb('export')
      or do {
         print("Program already running.\n");
         return;
      };

   print("Working...\n");
   sleep(10);   
   print("done.\n");
}

main();
```

Output:

[image: Output]

In the future, please provide a demonstration of your problem in your question.